# VBA - Repeat email function through multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

So I built a code that works for mailing 1 list (in Column A): Cell A1 has a region, Cells A2 though last row have an email address that needs that email. This code works fine for column A. But if a made a list in Columns B-#( however many number of columns), could i add onto this code and make it create as many emails as there are columns, and send them to the list of people below row 2.

In other words, can we make this say for Each column with a value in the first row create and email and send it to everyone else below it?

thanks

```
Sub emailfromcolumns()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MailMessage As String
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Namelist As String
LastRow = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


'email recipients are in row 2 to the last row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("Recipients").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
Namelist = Namelist & ";" & Sheets("Recipients").Range("A" & i).Value
End If

Next

MailMessage = "<HTML><BODY> Good Afternoon All, <br><br>" _
        & "<li>Please let me know if there is anything else you need or any changes you would like to see.<br><br>" _
        & "<li>Thanks,<br><br>" _
        & "Thank you, Pricing Team<br><br>" _


Set olApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")

If olApp Is Nothing Then

Set olApp = CreateObject(Class:="outlook.application")

End If

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    .To = Namelist
    .Subject = Range("A1").Value & " 60 Day Expiration " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now)))
    .display
    .HTMLBody = MailMessage
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\60 Day Exp\Savefiles\" & Range("A1").Value & " 60 Day Expirations " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & ".xlsx")
    .Save
    .Close 1
    End With

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub emailfromcolumns()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MailMessage As String
Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Namelist As String
Dim colCount As Long

'How Many Columns?
colCount = 4

'Loop through columns
For z = 1 To colCount

'email recipients are in row 2 to the last row
Namelist = vbNullString
With Worksheets("Recipients")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, z).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, z).Value <> "" Then
            Namelist = Namelist & ";" & .Cells(i, z).Value
        End If
    Next
End With

'Only create message if emails exist?
If Len(Namelist) > 0 Then

    MailMessage = "<HTML><BODY> Good Afternoon All, <br><br>" _
            & "<li>Please let me know if there is anything else you need or any changes you would like to see.<br> " _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<li>Thanks,<br><br>" _
            & "Thank you, Pricing Team<br><br>" _

    Set olApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject(Class:="outlook.application")
    End If

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    With olMail
        .To = Namelist
        .Subject = Sheets("Recipients").Cells(1, z).Value & " 60 Day Expiration " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now)))
        .display
        .HTMLBody = MailMessage
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\60 Day Exp\Savefiles\" & Sheets("Recipients").Cells(1, z).Value & " 60 Day Expirations " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & ".xlsx")
        .Save
        .Close 1
    End With

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End If

Next z

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make your existing routine accept a column number so you can pass any column to it, and then it will work for that column e.g.

```
Sub emailfromcolumns(COL As Long)
```

So then you can just call `emailfromcolumns(1)` to email for column A, `emailfromcolumns(2)` to email for column B etc.

Then you can create a second sub routine that finds out how many columns there are and just loops through them all, calling your existing routine:

```
Sub loopit()
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim x As Long
    lastColumn = Sheets("Recipients").Cells(1, Sheets("Recipients").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 1 To lastColumn
        emailfromcolumns (x)
    Next x
End Sub
```

This means all you have to do to your existing code is replace any reference to column "A" with the variable `COL` - there are four lines:

change

```
LastRow = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

to

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
```

change

```
If Sheets("Recipients").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
Namelist = Namelist & ";" & Sheets("Recipients").Range("A" & i).Value
End If
```

to

```
If Cells(2, COL).Value2 <> "" Then
    Namelist = Namelist & ";" & Cells(i, COL).Value2
End If
```

and the last two lines are within the e-mail bit:

```
.Subject = Sheets("Recipients").Cells(i, COL).Value2 & " 60 Day Expiration " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now)))
.Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\60 Day Exp\Savefiles\" & Sheets("Recipients").Cells(i, COL).Value2 & " 60 Day Expirations " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & ".xlsx")
```

On top of this, your code has some risky sections where you're just referring to `Range` without declaring which sheet the range is on... below is full version tidied up with comments on the differences:

```
Sub emailfromcolumns(COL As Long)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MailMessage As String
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Namelist As String
Dim WS As Worksheet ' Declare a worksheet object
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Recipients") ' set the worksheet object WS to "Recipients" for easy reference

LastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row ' last row now definitely referencing "Recipients" thanks to WS

'email recipients are in row 2 to the last row
' changed your "A2" check to outside the loop, don't need to check it each time
If WS.Cells(2, COL).Value2 <> "" Then
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Namelist = Namelist & ";" & WS.Cells(i, COL).Value2
    Next i
End If

MailMessage = "<HTML><BODY> Good Afternoon All, <br><br>" _
        & "<li>Please let me know if there is anything else you need or any changes you would like to see.<br><br>" _
        & "<li>Thanks,<br><br>" _
        & "Thank you, Pricing Team<br><br>" _


Set olApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
If olApp Is Nothing Then Set olApp = CreateObject(Class:="outlook.application")

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    .To = Namelist
    .Subject = WS.Cells(1, COL).Value2 & " 60 Day Expiration " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now)))
    .display
    .HTMLBody = MailMessage
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\60 Day Exp\Savefiles\" & WS.Cells(1, COL).Value2 & " 60 Day Expirations " & Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & ".xlsx")
    .Save
    .Close 1
End With

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' You didn't have anywhere that says Application.ScreenUpdating = False ?

End Sub
```